# Pattern of collision of bouncy balls in a sphere?

Tags: trigonometry, lagrange-multiplier, spherical-coordinates

Suppose that you have two infinitely bouncy golf balls that exist inside a perfect  sphere in weightless suspension, and both golf balls start bouncing at a random angle and are 10 or 100 times smaller than the container. The balls can either be zero friction and whatever simple friction scenarios can easily be applied in algebra.

What kinds of different patterns of collision in between the golf balls would occur and how can you categorize them? What study in mathematics is the problem described by?

Comment: ... at least non of the studies matching the tags you added, I suppose. I don't have better ideas, though

Comment: Can you please suggest some better tags.

Comment: Maybe more suited for http://physics.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Sorry i added a bit about a sphere with millions of golf balls and how interrelated their movements are, except that the question is probably best being simpler, sorry.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by "what types of collision"; the two balls con contact at a point. Mathematically, one or both could simultaneously be in contact with the containing sphere, but I believe the probability of that is zero with "random initial positions and velocities". (Separately, I'm not a physicist, but if you're interested in bound nucleons I believe "hard elastic spheres" are not a good model.)

Comment: If you left the golf balls to react for many thousands of bounces, and you plot the coordinates of every collision only in between the two golf balls, some kind of organized chaos pattern would emerge. Perhaps it would be similar to a three-dimensional spirograph. I would love to hear a comparison in between the maths of bouncy balls and theoretical trajectory deviations of more complex ethereal magnetic objects.